# New points not drawn on the map

Tags: point, geotools

I'm using geotools v14.3 to load a shapefile (Java Swing application). I want to allow the customers to use the mouse to click on the map area to draw new points, lines and polygons. First, I'm testing the points. So, a customer should be able to draw a point on the clicked location.

**My current approach**

After following few articles, I first capture the clicked mouse location with a mapmouselistener.

```
@Override
    public void onMouseClicked(MapMouseEvent ev) {
        System.out.println("mouse clicked : " + ev.getWorldPos());
        DirectPosition2D p = ev.getWorldPos();
        drawMyPoint(p.getX(), p.getY());

    }
```

Point drawing function is as follows.

```
void drawMyPoint(double x, double y) {
        SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder b = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
        b.setName("MyFeatureType");

        // set crs
        b.setCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
        // add geometry
        b.add("location", Point.class);

        // build the type
        final SimpleFeatureType TYPE = b.buildFeatureType();

        // create features using the type defined
        SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(TYPE);
        GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
        com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(x, y));
        featureBuilder.add(point);
        SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature("FeaturePoint");
        DefaultFeatureCollection featureCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection("internal", TYPE);
        featureCollection.add(feature); //Add feature 1
        // Add feature 2, 3, etc

        Style style = SLD.createPointStyle("Star", Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE, 0.3f, 15);
        Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection, style);
        layer.setTitle("NewPoint");
        map.addLayer(layer);
        mapPane.repaint();

    }
```

**Problem**

I can see the layer name being added to the map layer table. But the point is not visible on the map.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely answer is [axis order](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/order.html) - if you check the [DirectPosition2D API docs](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/geometry/DirectPosition2D.html) you will see the following warning:

> This class inherits x and y fields. But despite their names, they
>   don't need to be oriented toward East and North. The (x,y) axis can
>   have any orientation and should be understood as "ordinate 0" and
>   "ordinate 1" values instead. This is not specific to this
>   implementation; in Java2D too, the visual axis orientation depend on
>   the affine transform in the graphics context. The rational for
>   avoiding axis orientation restriction is that other DirectPosition
>   implementation do not have such restriction, and it would be hard to
>   generalize (what to do with North-East direction?).

Yet when creating the Point later on to display on your map you have treated them as X & Y without checking. To be safe you should wrap that creation with some check code like:

```
        if (CRS.getAxisOrder(crs)
                .equals(AxisOrder.NORTH_EAST)) {
            points[i] = geomFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(
                    x, y));
        } else {
            points[i] = geomFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(
                    y, x));
        }
```

Comment: Thank yout @iant for the helpful answer. I just commented the crs setting code and it started working.
        // set crs
        b.setCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
To brief what I did, I load a shape file layer first, then add a mouse listener, as I wanted users to add new nodes on to the map. When I comment the above setCRS() for a new point, it succeeded. 
Any hint why this happens?
And I will read and test what was proposed.

Comment: Instead of assuming your map is in lat/lon you should probably do b.setCRS(map.getCoordinateReferenceSystem());